# Android and Gradle: Unable to find java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

Tags: android, gradle

i wanted to try the new android build system gradle, so i installed gradle 1.2 and downloaded the samples for android.

when i try to build the basic sample with the command gradle build, i get the following output / error:

```
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.1/gradle
-0.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/0.1/build
er-0.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.1/gradle
-0.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/0.1/build
er-0.1.jar
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:generateDebugBuildConfig
:crunchDebugRes
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugRes
:compileDebug
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
:compileDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 18.926 secs
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you building just one of the samples?
if not, can you paste your build.gradle file?

Comment: i tried to build the basic sample without any modifications

Comment: yes, windows too,it works fine on my mac...

Comment: Yeah I think that's the problem. I've identified a couple of places where windows paths won't work. sigh.

Comment: too bad.. thanks for the information! I´m looking forward to a fix, the new system looks very promissing on the mac :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in 0.2 which is now available in Maven.